# Need to update AJAX url variable after Instagram AJAX call is complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, instagram

I have code to retrieve more photos from my Instagram self feed after the page is loaded using an AJAX call. It's triggered by a button click on the page. The code works but it keeps retrieving the same photos. I know its because the AJAX url keeps having the same value. I'm trying to update the AJAX url after the AJAX call is complete. I initially set the AJAX url variable using PHP. I have code inside the AJAX success function to update the variable but it doesn't seem to work. I just want to take the next_url value that is returned from the AJAX call and make a new request to Instagram. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
$('#more').click(function() {
            var nexturl = '<?php echo $nexturl; ?>';
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: nexturl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: "callback",
                jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
                success: function(data) {
                    // Output data
                    $.each(data.data, function(index, item) {
                            $('#photos').append('<div class="col-md-4"><img class="media" src="' + data.data[index].images.low_resolution.url + '"><div class="content"><div class="avatar" style="background-image: url(' + data.data[index].caption.from.profile_picture + ')"></div><p>' + data.data[index].caption.from.username + '</p><p>' + data.data[index].likes.count + ' likes</p><div class="comment">Comments:' + data.data[index].caption.text + '</div></div></div>');
                    });
                    // If the next url is not null or blank:
                    if ( data.pagination.next_url ) {
                        nexturl = data.pagination.next_url;
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //alert("Check you internet Connection");
                    $("#log").val($("#log").val() + 'Error\n');
                }
            }); 
        });
```

UPDATE:
Here's my new approach that works:

```
        // Show 'load more' button
    <?php echo "<br><button id=\"more\" data-nexturl=\"{$nexturl}\">Load      more</button>"; ?>
</div>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#more').click(function() {             
                nexturl = $(this).data('nexturl');              
            $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: nexturl,
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              jsonp: "callback",
              jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {
                // Output data
                $.each(data.data, function(index, item) {
                    $('#photos').append('<div class="col-md-4"><img class="media" src="' + data.data[index].images.low_resolution.url + '"><div class="content"><div class="avatar" style="background-image: url(' + data.data[index].user.profile_picture + ')"></div><p>' + data.data[index].user.username + '</p><p>' + data.data[index].likes.count + ' likes</p></div></div>');
                });                 
                // Store new next_url
                $('#more').data('nexturl', data.pagination.next_url);
              }
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The subsequent click will use this variable `var nexturl = '<?php echo $nexturl; ?>';` again?

Comment: I want to update the nexturl variable, I just don't know how to do it. I want to populate the variable using PHP first but then with every button click use data.pagination.next_url that is returned after the AJAX call is finished.

Comment: I solved it by using a different approach. I store the next_url response in a html data element and update the element every time the button is clicked.